# Error calling two zip functions in succession

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, zip

I have two lists, id and name, and I want to zip them together and output them in two different ways. The first way separates the zip tuples and outputs the ID along with the corresponding name in a string. The second way should just output the zip tuples themselves.

When I run this code, the first for loop executes before receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\Alan\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module> for item in zip(id,name):

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

The confusing part is that if I comment out one for loop and run the other alone, I can successfully run each one. Since both arguments passed in are iterable lists, I'm unsure why the error says the first argument must support iteration. Any help is appreciated.

```
id=[117,234,821,257,265,489]
name=['john','max','aaron','jim','sierra','kat']

for id, name in zip(id,name):
    print(f'ID {id} is associated with {name}')

for item in zip(id,name):
    print(item)
```

Comment: You are just shadowing the name of your list `id` with the name of your variable in the loop `id`, next to `name`. Hence, it won't run. Also, I'd suggest using a different name to `id` since `id` is already a Python function.  See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Answer (score 0):

```
# just change the first for loop variable name to something other than id
id=[117,234,821,257,265,489]
name=['john','max','aaron','jim','sierra','kat']

for idx, name in zip(id,name):
    print(f'ID {idx} is associated with {name}')

for item in zip(id,name):
    print(item)
```

Comment: I tried this and while it gets rid of the error, it doesn't return the output I wanted. The first for loop runs fine and prints out all the names and ids, but the second only prints (117, 'k'), (234, 'a'), and (821, 't'). It looks like the 2nd for loop is taking the first 3 ids and zipping them with the 3 characters of the final name.

Comment: @Alan Update the list name 'name' to 'names' or 'name1' and then the above code work as expected. Avoid using python's built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the same names you have used for variables and lists in the first for-loop, so when you call again id and name in the second for-loop these names reference to variables and not to lists. The following example should work. (Also avoid use id because is a python's built-in function as already has mentioned.)

```
ids=[117,234,821,257,265,489]
names=['john','max','aaron','jim','sierra','kat']

for idx, name in zip(ids,names):
    print(f'ID {idx} is associated with {name}')

for item in zip(ids,names):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the 2nd for loop doesn't run properly with this code. Please see my other reply to @sk11 for an explanation of what happens.

Comment: Perhaps you 've done some typo error, the 2nd for-loop run properly, here is my output:

ID 117 is associated with john
ID 234 is associated with max
ID 821 is associated with aaron
ID 257 is associated with jim
ID 265 is associated with sierra
ID 489 is associated with kat
(117, 'john')
(234, 'max')
(821, 'aaron')
(257, 'jim')
(265, 'sierra')
(489, 'kat')